# Помогите с вопросом Flexbox and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Добрый день  друзья помогите с вопросом  `flexbox`  и  `JavaScript`.

Вопрос касается кросс-браузерностьи  сайта.

```
function switchFunction(inside) {
  var i,  openblock;
  openblock = document.getElementsByClassName("switch-block");
  for (i = 0; i < openblock.length; i++) {
    openblock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(inside).style.display = "flex";
}

.switch-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Как внедрить  префикс  в код

Comment: С чем у вас проблема? класс добавить? js код? Или назначить элементам на странице этот класс?

Comment: Вы ведь ожидаете ответ с примером кода в котором можно легко разобраться и легко использовать у себя, правда? Так может свой код подправите так чтобы было более понятно тем кто пытается вам помочь?

Answer (score 1):

js КОД

```
function switchFunction(inside){
        var i, openblock;
        openblock=document.getElementsByClassName("switch-block");
        for(i=0; i<openblock.length; i++){
        openblock[i].style.display="none";
        }
        document.getElementById(inside).style.display="flex";
        }
```

HTML КОД

```
 <div class="category" onclick="switchFunction('one')"><h1 role="definition">Industrial</h1></div>
<div class="category" onclick="switchFunction('two')"><h1 role="definition">Photo</h1></div>
<div class="category" onclick="someFunction('three')"><h1 role="definition">Sport</h1></div>
<div class="category" onclick="switchFunction('four')"><h1 role="definition">Other</h1></div>

<div class="switch-block" id="one" name="Industrial"></div>
<div class="switch-block" id="two" name="Photo"></div>
<div class="switch-block" id="three" name="Sport"></div>
<div class="switch-block" id="four" name="Other"></div>
```

CSS КОД

```
 .switch-block{
                       display:-webkit-box;
                       display:-webkit-flex;
                       display:-moz-box;
                       display:-moz-flex;
                       display:-ms-flexbox;
                       display:flex;
                       -webkit-box-direction:normal;
                       -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
                      -webkit-flex-flow:row nowrap;
                        -moz-box-direction:normal;
                       -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
                      -moz-flex-flow:row nowrap;
                     -ms-flex-flow:row nowrap;
                       flex-flow:row nowrap;

    }
```

Спасибо вам  за  ответ и извените за  некоректный вопрос .

По этой размете  я  создал переключатели. Мне нужно держать  кросс-браузерность  в блоке `switch-block`.Как можно  это делать.Заранее спасибо

Comment: Не надо в ответах писать вопросы.. Надо было свой вопрос `править`, снизу вопроса есть одноименная кнопка...